# increasing pandas dataframe imputation performance

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, runtime

I want to impute a large datamatrix (90*90000) and later an even larger one (150000*800000) using pandas. 
At the moment I am testing with the smaller one on my laptop (8gb ram, Haswell core i5 2.2 GHz, the larger dataset will be run on a server).

The columns have some missing values that I want to impute with the most frequent one over all rows.

My working code for this is:

```
freq_val =  pd.Series(mode(df.ix[:,6:])[0][0], df.ix[:,6:].columns.values) #most frequent value per column, starting from the first SNP column (second row of 'mode'gives actual frequencies)
df_imputed = df.ix[:,6:].fillna(freq_val) #impute unknown SNP values with most frequent value of respective columns
```

The imputation takes about 20 minutes on my machine. Is there another implementation that would increase performance?

Comment: You could test isolating the indexes where the row includes a `NaN`, then manually set the cell to the mode using `.loc()` . I don't know if it'd give you better performance but it's an alternative to test.

Comment: @AlexPetralia Thanks for the input, I tried this approach, but masking the `NaN` values does not yield any major improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried different approaches. The key learning is that the `mode` function is really slow. Alternatively, I implemented the same functionality using `np.unique` (`return_counts=True`) and `np.bincount`. The latter is supposedly faster, but it doesn't work with `NaN` values.

The optimized code now needs about 28 s to run. MaxU's answer needs ~48 s on my machine to finish.

The code:

```
iter = range(np.shape(df.ix[:,6:])[1])
freq_val = np.zeros(np.shape(df.ix[:,6:])[1])
for i in iter:
    _, count = np.unique(df.ix[:,i+6], return_counts=True)
    freq_val[i] = count.argmax()
freq_val_series =  pd.Series(freq_val, df.ix[:,6:].columns.values) 
df_imputed = df.ix[:,6:].fillna(freq_val_series)
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
df_imputed = df.iloc[:, 6:].fillna(df.iloc[:, 6:].apply(lambda x: x.mode()).iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this implementation, but it is about 40% slower than the solution I found. See answer below.